# Copy File Path with Double Backslashes for Windows

Tags: windows, path

When I **SHIFT** and **right click** on a file in Windows Explorer windows, it provides `Copy as path` menu option.

But when I use it, it copies the path with single backslash

```
"C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\filename.txt"
```

Is there any option so that I can copy the path as double backslashed automatically as below?

```
"C:\\Users\\Andrew\\Desktop\\filename.txt"
```

Because I use the double backslashed version in programming, it becomes cumbersome to type all double backslashes manually.

Comment: You can use Resharper (or a similiar helper tool) and it will suggest to escape the slashes for you.